# How to use wheel odometry for mapping with SLAM Toolbox

Tags: ros2, slam, robot-localization

I am currently trying to do mapping with a mobile robot using SLAM Toolbox, I have the odometry setup from the wheel encoders and an IMU, however I noted the SLAM toolbox node isn't subscribed to the `/odometry/filtered` topic or the `/tf` so I wonder how does it know its pose, my guess is that the toolbox estimates the pose based on the Lidar data and I want to know if it is possible to include my odometry information to make the mapping more accurate. I am using ROS 2 Humble on Ubuntu 22.04.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Which mapping algorithm are you using? As I can see, **cartographer** is subscribing to pose data and to IMU data, then filters them and extrapolate real robot pose in the map. (https://ros2-industrial-workshop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/high_level_system_overview.png).
I think you should take care of topic names that nodes are subscribing to.